# xdebug - timeout error and failed to load error with v2.2.5 and v2.5.5 for php 5.2.6/xampp/zend

Tags: php, xampp, xdebug

I am usign xampp. php version 5.6.28. Thread Safe. opcache disabled.

xdebug version that comes with xampp is 2.2.5

I am running xampp in Windows 10 Enterprise 64 bit.

INI Settings are

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension=php_xdebug.dll
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
```

From the command line php -v I get

```
C:\Users\733283>php -v PHP 5.6.28 (cli) (built: Nov  9 2016 06:40:27)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright
(c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by Derick Rethans
```

When I ran the application by enabling xdebug I get session time out error in some line of php code. When I searched I got the following. https://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=1424. It is mentioned that it has been  fixed in xdebug version 2.5.4 . From their download page I downloaded the xdebug version php_xdebug-2.5.5-5.6-vc11-x86_64.dll for php version 5.6.2. (They have mentioned both 2.5.4 and 2.5.5 works with php 5.6.2). I copied to the ext folder and modified the php.ini file as

```
zend_extension = php_xdebug-2.5.5-5.6-vc11-x86_64.dll
```

I tested this by running php -v from the command line. I got the following.

```
C:\Users\733283>php -v
Failed loading C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.5.5-5.6-vc11-x86_64.dll
PHP 5.6.28 (cli) (built: Nov  9 2016 06:40:27)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

When I tried their https://xdebug.org/docs/install I can see for php 5.6 the versions of xdebug 2.5 and 2.4 are mentioned. I tried both but got the same above output.

When I tried their testing page it says

```
Tailored Installation Instructions
Summary
Xdebug installed: no
Server API: Command Line Interface
Windows: yes - Compiler: MS VC11 - Architecture: x86
Zend Server: no
PHP Version: 5.6.28
Zend API nr: 220131226
PHP API nr: 20131226
Debug Build: no
Thread Safe Build: yes
OPcache Loaded: no
Configuration File Path: C:\WINDOWS
Configuration File: C:\xampp\php\php.ini
Extensions directory: C:\xampp\php\ext
PHP version 5.6 is not supported.
```

But their install page says xdebug version 2.5 works with php v5.6

I have also raised a issue in their website. https://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=1678.

How to make it work?

Comment: Have you considered upgrading your XAMPP / PHP version to PHP 7.2 or newer? Or that has to be 5.6?.. *"But their install page says xdebug version 2.5 works with php v5.6"* It works. It's just that page/wizard does not support 5.x any more -- to encourage you to upgrade to latest PHP version (and therefore newer Xdebug .. where certain bugs are fixed already).

Comment: *"Failed loading C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.5.5-5.6-vc11-x86_64.dll"* -- this is for 64-bit PHP .. while you seems to run 32 bit one (`Windows: yes - Compiler: MS VC11 - Architecture: x86`). Try downloading this one instead: https://xdebug.org/files/php_xdebug-2.5.5-5.6-vc11.dll

Comment: oh my gaat. Since the computer system is 64bit i was assuming that the installation will also be 64bit. phew. I changed to a 32 bit and it is loading. But, i am getting timeout errors. i set it to 500 seconds. still it throws timeout error after 500 seconds. . i set it to 0 to make it infinite. the script is executing infinitely. I am using zend fw and the code uses loop and db selects extensively. so that particular module is taking infinitely to execute when xdebug is enabled. I will check SO for that. If you have any comment to make for the timeout then please do so. Thank you.

Comment: Create a reproducible small project -- then it can be looked into. Otherwise -- no ideas as it might be specific to your PC/setup (other components etc).